# How to add an anonymous page in web application which authenticated with ADFS?

Tags: wif, adfs

I have a WIF web application which authenticated with ADFS. I need to create an intermediate page which can be accessed anonymously. So when an anonymous user access website, it always open this intermediate page, from there, user can click 'Sign In' button or HyberLink to redirect to ADFS. After authenticated by ADFS, redirect back to real web page(such as 'Profile' page). When authenticated user click 'Sign Out' button, it should redirect back to intermediate page(anonymous page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "unprotect" any page using the standard ASP.NET security configuration.  In web.config you could add :

```
  <location path="openpage.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

On the page you can just put a button to redirect to the adfs login page and logout page (You can create the correct urls using SigninRequestMessage and SIgnOutRequestMessage.

p.e. :

```
            var request = new SignInRequestMessage(new Uri("http://adfslocation"), "originalRealm")
                      {
                          Reply = "http://localhost/openpage.aspx"
                      };
Then you can redirect to request.WriteQueryString();
```